# How to use bluetooth controller connected to an Android phone on my PC?

Tags: windows-xp, android, bluetooth, game-controller

I have a bluetooth controller connected to an Android device. How do I use this setup to pass the game controller button presses to my computer since it doesn't have bluetooth. So basically, I want to use the Android device as a bridge to get the controller working on the PC.

Comment: I don't know of any apps that can do this.

Comment: I'm currently using KinoConsole, it works because it sends the controller input to the PC. However, it also streams the video with no way of turning it off, making the phone lag. So I guess I'm looking for a solution similar to KinoConsole but without the remote desktop view capability with and possibly lesser latency in the input on my PC.